# Remove duplicate values from a string in classic asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have below code in classic asp

```
 str=Request.Form("txt_str")
```

"txt_str" is text box in a classic asp form page where I am entering below values:
000-00001 
000-00001 
000-00001
000-00002

```
response.write str
```

hence str will be 000-00001 000-00001 000-00001 000-00002

```
array = split(str,Chr(44))  

if str <> "" then
    x=empty
    for i = 0 to ubound(array) 
        if array(i) <> "" then
            array_2 = split(array(i),chr(13) & chr(10))  
            for j = 0 to ubound(array_2)
                if array_2(j) <> "" then
                    if x=empty then

                        x=  "'" & array_2(j) & "'"
                    else
                        x= x & ",'"  & array_2(j) & "'"
                    end if
                end if
            next
        end if
    next
End if

response.write x
```

hence x will be returned as  '000-00001','000-00001','000-00001','000-00002'

I want to remove duplicate values from x and display only it as:

x = '000-00001','000-00002'

How can i achieve this.Any help on this would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove duplicates of string lists, the best option IMO is to use a Dictionary object. You can use this short function to do the task on a given string array:

```
    Function getUniqueItems(arrItems)
        Dim objDict, strItem

        Set objDict = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        For Each strItem in arrItems
            objDict.Item(strItem) = 1
        Next

        getUniqueItems = objDict.Keys
    End Function
```

A simple test:

```
    ' -- test output
    Dim arrItems, strItem

    arrItems = Array("a","b","b","c","c","c","d","e","e","e")

    For Each strItem in getUniqueItems(arrItems)
        Response.Write "<p>" & strItem & "</p>"
    Next
```

This is a sample for your use case:

```
    ' -- sample for your use case
    Dim strInput, x

    strInput = Request.Form("txt_str")
    x = "'" & join(getUniqueItems(split(str, Chr(44))), "','") & "'"
```

BTW, did you notice that `Array` and `Str` are VBScript Keywords, so you may run into issues with using such variable names. Therefore, I think it is common practice in VBScript to use prefixes for variable names.

Comment: Definitely a clear and well written response. Gets my vote.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a ordered list, consider using a variable with last value:

```
lastval = ""
array = split(str,Chr(44))  

if str <> "" then
    x=empty
    for i = 0 to ubound(array) 
        if array(i) <> "" then
            array_2 = split(array(i),chr(13) & chr(10))  
            for j = 0 to ubound(array_2)
                if array_2(j) <> "" then
                    if array_2(j) <> lastval then                          
                       lastval = array_2(j) 
                       if x=empty then
                           x=  "'" & array_2(j) & "'"
                       else
                           x= x & ",'"  & array_2(j) & "'"
                       end if
                    end if
                end if
            next
        end if
    next
End if
```

Comment: @user1783170  Can you explain what did not work?  Do you still have a `response.write x` at the end?